# Serial Flash always returning 0x00 while reading after writing

Tags: pic, spi, flash, mplab, xc8

Could someone look into the code and tell me the mistake in the code

I am trying to Interface PIC16F877a and AT25SF041 serial flash.

I have pulled up CS pin to 5V using 1K resistor
The flash is powered by 3.5V(Vcc) obtained from LM317. The WP,Hold pins have been connected to Vcc(3.3V)

Coding is done using MPLAB X IDE, using XC8 compiler.

```
void spiInit()
{
   SSPSTAT=0x00;
   SSPCON=0x20;
   TRISCbits.TRISC2=0;
   TRISCbits.TRISC3=0;
   TRISCbits.TRISC4=1;    
   TRISCbits.TRISC5=0;
   SS=1;
}
void spiWrite(char Wdata)
{
   SSPBUF=Wdata;
   while(BF);
}
char spiRead()
{
   while(!BF);
   return SSPBUF;
}
```

Erase Function:

```
void Erase()
{
  SS=1;
  SS=0;
  spiWrite(0xD8);
  spiWrite(0x01);
  spiWrite(0x01);
  spiWrite(0x01);
  SS=1;
}
```

Write enable Function:

```
void writeEnable()
{
  SS=1;
  SS=0;
  spiWrite(0x06);
  SS=1;
}
```

Write Function:

```
void Write(char txData)
{
   int i=0;
   SS=0;    
   spiWrite(0x02);
   spiWrite(0x01);
   spiWrite(0x01);
   spiWrite(0x01);
   spiWrite(txData);
   i++;
   SS=1;
}
```

Read function :

```
char Read()
{
   char rxData;
   SS=0;
   spiWrite(0x03);
   spiWrite(0x01);
   spiWrite(0x01);
   spiWrite(0x01);
   rxData=spiRead();
   SS=1;
}
```

These are my functions and all am trying to do is write a character to the flash and read the same

```
void main()
{
  spiInit();
  RC1=0;
  Erase();
  __delay_ms(100);
  writeEnable();
  Write('A');                         //Write
  __delay_ms(100);
  rx=Read();                          //Read
  while(1);
}
```

but the value read is always **0x00**
could someone point out my mistake.
Here is my Circuit(crystal oscillator, Vdd, Ground have been excluded from the circuit diagram).[image: Circuit]

Thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: "The flash is powered by 3.3V(Vcc) obtained by stepping down 5V using voltage divider circuit." this is most likely your problem, as your load is not constant, the voltage will also not be.

Comment: @PlasmaHH But across Vcc and GND pin of flash, its showing 3.34V in multimeter after completing the whole circuit. Do you think, voltage divider is not the suitable option for stepping down the voltage?

Comment: A multimeter can't possibly show you the rapid dips in supply voltage caused by the increased current consumption while writing to the FLASH cells. You need a proper 3.3V regulator.

Comment: You will need an oscilloscope to view the voltage on the resistor divider when writing. A multimeter is waaaay too slow.

Comment: @TurboJ Oscilloscope is one among the many things that i don't have as of now.

Comment: @Finbarr As per the data sheet, the Vcc should be between 2.5 - 3.6V. So thought that 3.3 will be perfect. Will give a try on another power supply.

Comment: @Sreez..: Just because you don't have the scope and can't observe things it doesn't mean that your voltage drops aren't there. A voltage divider is not a proper way to power any device, especially one that needs high currents in short bursts. The voltage you see depends on the current your load draws, if you like it or not. Just try calculating the voltage at a divider with a high and a low resistance as load and you shall see the difference.

Comment: 3.3V is just fine as long as it stays at 3.3V. But you have no idea how low it's dropping as the load changes.

Comment: @PlasmaHH thank you for giving me a thought about that. Will try using another power source soon. I hope that the code part is good.

Comment: @Sreez.. - In addition to the helpful advice given by other members regarding the Vcc supply, you said that you have: "pulled up CS pin to 5V using 2K resistor". This is **not allowed** and doing that *might* have damaged your flash memory device. That signal should be pulled-up to the correct Vcc voltage and *not to a higher voltage*.

Comment: @SamGibson Thanks for correcting me. Did that in that workflow ,my bad. Planning on using voltage regulator (LM317). Will that work?

Comment: Depends what voltage you have available to supply it. The LM317 needs about 3V between input and output so if all you have is 5V it won't be enough. Look for a 3.3V LDO regulator instead.

Comment: @Sreez.. "Planning on using voltage regulator (LM317). Will that work?" The answer depends on how *you* use it in your design - there is no definite answer to your hypothetical question, as it doesn't contain the necessary details. Read its datasheet, consider things like input-to-output differential voltage (dropout voltage) etc. If you are just using it to create a fixed 3.3V supply, then it seems an unusual choice, but perhaps you have reasons which we don't know for choosing it (e.g. local market availability).

Comment: swapped the power source for the flash with LM317, but still no luck. Cant read anything from the flash.All i get is 0x00.

Comment: Which is it, 0x00, or 0xFF as the topic says?

Comment: @pipe its 0x00, 0xff was the output when i started this thread. Now after a series of trials the output became 0x00.(Am afraid whether i damaged it)